# Grid in Kendo UI MVC cannot edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid

I created a `Grid` using Kendo UI MVC to manage database for Admin user. Yesterday it could edited, but now I cannot edit or click any button in `Grid`. I don't know what happened with them? Does someone knows any solutions for this situation?

`.cshtml`:

```
@using AdventureCycle.Models
@model IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductSubcategoryID).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductCategoryID).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.NameofBike).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(190);
        columns.Template(c => { }).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("", "StoreManager") + "/#= ID #'" + "><img src='../GetImage.ashx?ID=@bike.ProductProductPhotoes.FirstOrDefault().ProductPhotoID' /></a>").Width(150).Title("Picture");
        columns.Bound(c => c.isSelected).Width(120);
    })

    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .ToolBar(tb => 
    {
        tb.Create();
        tb.Save();
    })
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Batch(true)
                                .ServerOperation(false)
                                .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.ProductID))
                                .Read("GetSub","Grid")
                                .Update("UpdateSub","Grid")
                                .Create("InsertSub","Grid")
                                .Destroy("DeleteSub","Grid"))

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Server Operation false is what is causing the problem, if not

Try using a Lambda expression in your update and edit commands

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Orders"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("Orders_Update", "Orders"))
      .Destroy(update => update.Action("Orders_Delete", "Orders"))
```